# laravel router argument behaviour

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I notice that when you use URL:::action, and set some arguments, sometimes laravel would cast them as GET requests, sometimes not.
Is there anyone know why and how to controller it?

```
echo URL::action('Campaign\\CampaignController@getIndex',['para' => 1]),"<br>";
echo URL::action('Campaign\\CampaignController@getOtherAction',['para' => 1]),"<br>";
echo URL::action('Campaign\\CampaignController@getOtherAction2',['para' => 1]),"<br>";
```

Output:

```
/campaign?para=1
/campaign/other-action/1
/campaign/other-action2/1
```

Note the getIndex gets argument as GET (?para=1)

Comment: post your route file also

Answer (score 0):

This happens because system cannot differentiate requests to `getIndex` from others if they pass it as url segment.

Means

`/campaign/other-action/1` translates to `other-action` as a method with `1` as param

By your expectation

`/campaign/other-action/1` translates to `getIndex` as a method with `other-action/1` as param

Index methods are not suppose to have URL segments as inputs. If you need url segments as inputs then you will have to pass it as a get parameter and thats what laravel is doing for you.

According to your first route output,

if the url is `/campaign/1` which means it will expect a method named `get1`. Another example: if the url is `/campaign/param` system would expect a method `getParam`

**NOTE for fellow stackoverflow-ers:Consider asking questions before downvoting**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however,  it is more like explaining what is happening rather than why it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the reason.
when you are using route::controllers method, laravel would assume you have multiple parameters attached to each action

```
Route::controllers([
        'order' => 'Order\OrderController',
        'campaign' => 'Campaign\CampaignController'
    ]);
```

For example:

```
campaign/other-action/{VALUE1?}/{VALUE2?}/{VALUE3?}...
```

So when you pass `['para' => 1, 'para2' => 'abc']`, laravel will try to match parameters to action. in this case: `campaign/other-action/1/abc`

Avoiding to use Route::controllers, an help you take control on laravel router argument behaviour.

For example, in routes.php:

```
Route::get('campaign/other-action/{id}','Campaign\CampaignController@getOtherAction2')
```

when you give

```
echo URL::action('Campaign\\CampaignController@getOtherAction2',['id'=>366, 'para' => 1, 'para2' => 'abc']);
```

you will get what you want:

```
campaign/other-action/366?para=1&para2=abc
```

I hope it is helpful and I now understand why laravel remove Route::controllers from 5.3 version.